# How to keep a class alive like in Tabbed apps

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I currently have an app like this that has the drawer interface but when I go into another view everything resets in the current view and never stays the same ?

This is how my code looks like when I switch views.

```
           [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
            CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeChannel"];
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
            [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; }];
```

So my question is "How would I keep the view alive while going into another view such as the [tabbed apps](http://www.deviantpoint.com/image.axd?picture=PBImport/17-image_6_1a526dc8.png)  "

Such as my tableView, when I go to another view and back to the original one it resets.

[image: My image]

Comment: Generally one would assign an object to a local property with retain in order to keep it around.

Comment: What would I search so I could make a research about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a NSMutableArray that will keep a pointer to your views. Save the view when you leave it, fetch it when you need it back. Beware! This will consume a lot of memory, but that's what you asked for.

```
- (void)initArray
{
    myViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_VIEWS; i++)
    {
        [myViews addObject:[NSNull null]];
    }
}

- (void)saveView:(UIView*)view atIndex:(int)index
{
    myViews[index] = view;
}

- (UIView*)fetchViewAtIndex:(int)index
{
    UIView *view = myViews[index];
    if (view == [NSNull null])
        return nil;
    return view;
}
```